# how to disable a list element in swt list eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Is it possible to disable only certain elements of a swt list display.I want a list display with a certain clickable strings and a few disabled strings based on my conditions.Is it possible to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want it then add a selection listener that would detect if the selection is on the "disabled" item and then adjust up/down/clear selection depending on the list contents.

You may also use table with a single column - then you should be able to custom-draw disabled items (e.g. to use lighter font or a different background).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with `SWT List` widget. you might need to come up with your own widget( may be `Table` with one `Column`)